# Comparing two files based on md5 hash value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am using a find command to find files formatted 'DGT_????.JPG'. I am trying to get the script below to record the absolute paths of any file with the same name and the same hash from the source directory if it matches a file in target directory. I also want to enusure these files arent copied from source dirrectory to target directoyr. Then I want to record them into a new text file called 'dups.txt'. Can't seem to find a definite answer on the web so that's why I am posting this question. Thanks, fairly new to Linux.

My code is below

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
SRC="$1"
DEST="$2"

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "two arguments required"
fi

if [ ! -d "$SRC" ]; then
    echo "Source directory does not found"

fi


if [ ! -d "$DEST" ]; then
    mkdir "$DEST"
fi


for image in $(find "$SRC" -type f -iname DGT_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].JPG)
do
    md5sum=$(md5sum < "$image")        
    for duplicate in "$DEST"  
    do
        [ "$image" = "$duplicate" ] && continue      
        [ "$md5sum" = "$(md5sum < "$duplicate")" ] >> dups.txt  
    done
    cp --backup --suffix=.JPG     "$image" "$DEST"
done
```

Comment: How does this differ from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33894345/258523)? In the `dups.txt` creation?

Comment: I am trying to now find duplicates that also have the same hash value which don't copy and record them in a new text file called dups.txt. My last question was just about finding and copying all files with the format and appending duplicates with '.JPG'.

Comment: You absolutely do not want to be running `md5sum` on each file in your target directory for every new file. That is **horribly** expensive. You want to store the values in an array (an associative array if you have bash 4+) and compare against that.

Comment: Not too focused on that at the minute. Just want to record absolute pathnames of duplicates (filenames and hash value) into a txt file without copying to target folder.

Comment: Is this not working? How is it not working? Is it not writing to `dups.txt`? What are you expecting to have written to `dups.txt` from this code? Where are you writing the *filename* to `dups.txt` here?

Comment: It should show paths  of duplicate files. I currently get md5sum: is not a directory repeated on numerous lines. And I am using >> to append to file name, it is in the code.

Comment: You are appending the *output* of a `[` test to the file. What do you expect the output from that to be?

Comment: Do you mean `md5sum: is a directory`? That would be because you are running `md5sum < $DEST` where `$DEST` is a directory. That doesn't work. You need to run it on *all* the files. That was my point before.

Comment: Hi @EtanReisner, this is the problem, I am not sure. I am new to this and thus asking for help. I thought this would work. I just want the absolute pathnames of duplicates recorded. Sorry if that is no use to you but that is all I can say. And yes, I do

Comment: Run `[ "$md5sum" = "$(md5sum < somefile)" ]` and see what you get as output. Then add `set -x` to your script and see what command is actually being run that is failing. (Hint: As I already said it is the `md5sum < $duplicate` command because the contents of `$duplicate` aren't what you expect them to be.)

Comment: Changed the error and script runs fine, changed to "$DEST"/*, still nothing writing to dups.txt though

Comment: Did you run the `[ ... ]` command manually like I said? Did you see any output? If you want to write output to a file you need to actually create the output. You need to do that when the test is successful.

Comment: Just curious, what is actually being executed after the first pass with `md5sum=$(md5sum < "$image")` ?? Shouldn't we choose a new *variable name* to insure `md5sum` is actually calling the executable `md5sum` and not some hashed string of characters?

Comment: Hi, any tips on  how to do this though? Like I said, new to Linux and really am winging it.

Comment: "Do this" meaning "find duplicate files"? Use one of the many, many off-the-shelf tools (like `fdupes`, from https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes) for the purpose rather than trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, eh? The command being invoked is `md5sum`, not `$md5sum`. I agree that namespace collisions lead to confusion to readers, but not that there's actually a chance for real bugs related to same; if shell were a LISP, it'd be a LISP-2, not a LISP-1.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, yes it does lead to confusion to readers, it left this one scratching his head... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

jgot8 - I actually believe the task given out specifies that you should save these duplicate matches in a file called duplicates.txt, rather than dupes.txt

I trust that when I discuss this with you, you'll be able to explain the concepts fully in order to award your 35%?

We will discuss this tomorrow at 9am.

-Jim